# Визуальное редактирование содержимого контроллов [Android]

Tags: android, html, java

**Добрый день!**

Скажите, есть ли в Android возможность редактировать текст, например, кнопки или TextView с помощью HTML? К примеру, что-то наподобие:

```
...
TextView tv = <found textview>;
tv.setText("<b><i>Text</i><b>");
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><i>Text</i><b>"));
```

Comment: То, что нужно! Большое спасибо!